# Tensor products of Hilbert spaces and Hilbert-Schmidt operators

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

I am trying to get a better understanding of tensor products of Hilbert spaces. Suppose that $x,y\in\mathbb H$, where $\mathbb H$ is a Hilbert space. As far as I understand, we can think about the tensor $x\otimes y$ as a bounded linear operator from $\mathbb H$ to $\mathbb H$ defined by
$$
(x\otimes y)(z)=\langle z,y\rangle x
$$
for each $x\in\mathbb H$ and the tensor product $\mathbb H\otimes \mathbb H$ as the space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators from $\mathbb H$ to $\mathbb H$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces#Explicit_construction)). Let us denote the space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators from $\mathbb H$ to $\mathbb H$ by $HS(\mathbb H)$.

It seems that we can think about $x\otimes y$ as an element in a Hilbert space $HS(\mathbb H)$ and we can consider a tensor $x\otimes y\tilde\otimes z\otimes w$ with $x,y,z,w\in\mathbb H$ as an element in the tensor product $HS(\mathbb H)\tilde\otimes HS(\mathbb H)$.

> Does it make sense to define the tensor $x\otimes y\tilde\otimes z\otimes w$ by setting
>   $$
> (x\otimes y\tilde\otimes z\otimes w)(\varphi)=\langle\varphi,z\otimes w\rangle_{\mathrm{HS}}(x\otimes y)
> $$
>   for each $\varphi\in HS(\mathbb H)$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt inner product? This would mean that we can think about $\mathbb H\otimes \mathbb H\tilde\otimes \mathbb H\otimes \mathbb H$ as the space $HS(HS(\mathbb H))$ and, if $\varphi=u\otimes v$ for some $u,v
> \in\mathbb H$, we would have
>   $$
> (x\otimes y\tilde\otimes z\otimes w)(u\otimes v)
> =\langle u\otimes v,z\otimes w\rangle_{\mathrm{HS}} (x\otimes y)
> =\langle u,z\rangle\langle w,v\rangle(x\otimes y).
> $$

References (textbooks, papers, etc.) are very welcome. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I've never read a construction like this about tensor products between Hilbert Spaces, nonetheless, if your first characterization of tensor products is fine, there wouldn't be any reason to think that your characterizaction about tensor product between tensor products would be bad. Also, if you found some references about this I would appreciate if you could comment about them.