# Trace of $x\otimes y\tilde\otimes x\otimes y$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, trace

Suppose that $x,y\in\mathbb H$, where $\mathbb H$ is a separable Hilbert space. Define the tensor $x\otimes y:\mathbb H\to\mathbb H$ by setting $(x\otimes y)(z)=\langle z,y\rangle x$ for $z\in\mathbb H$. We can also define $A=x\otimes y\tilde\otimes x\otimes y: S_2(\mathbb H)\to S_2(\mathbb H)$ in an analogous way, where $S_2(\mathbb H)$ is the space of the Hilbert-Schmidt operators, which is also a Hilbert space. I am interested in the trace of $A$. On one hand,
$$
\operatorname{Tr}A=\operatorname{Tr}[x\otimes y\tilde\otimes x\otimes y]=\operatorname{Tr}[x\otimes y]\operatorname{Tr}[x\otimes y]=|\langle x,y\rangle|^2.
$$
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
 \operatorname{Tr}A
&=\sum_{k,l\ge1}\langle{A(e_k\otimes e_l),e_k\otimes e_l}\rangle_{\mathrm{HS}}\\
 &=\sum_{k,l\ge1}\langle\langle e_k\otimes e_l,x\otimes y\rangle_{\mathrm{HS}}(x\otimes y),e_k\otimes e_l\rangle_{\mathrm{HS}}\\
 &=\sum_{k,l\ge1}\langle x\otimes y,e_k\otimes e_l\rangle_{\mathrm{HS}}\langle e_k\otimes e_l,x\otimes y\rangle_{\mathrm{HS}}\\
 &=\|x\otimes y\|_{\mathrm{HS}}^2\\
 &=\|x\|^2\|y\|^2.
\end{align*}
Where am I making a mistake? Which is the correct answer?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: For Hilbert-Schmidt operators $S,T$ one defines the scalar product by $<S,T>_{HS}=Tr (ST^{*})$ and so if You view $x\otimes y$ as a Hilbert-Schmidt operator ($S_2(\mathbb{H})\cong \mathbb{H}\otimes\mathbb{H}$) then $||x\otimes y||_{HS}^2=Tr ((x\otimes y)(x\otimes y)^{*})$. I can't see how this is equal to $||x||^2||y||^2$

Comment: @PeterMelech $\|x\otimes y\|_{\mathrm{HS}}^2=\sum\|(x\otimes y)(e_k)\|^2=\|x\|^2\sum|\langle e_k,y\rangle|^2=\|x\|^2\|y\|^2$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert–Schmidt_operator)).

Comment: Sure! I can't find a mistake either. Good question!

Answer (score 1):

Alright to first clear up how maps of the form $(x\otimes y)\tilde\otimes(z\otimes w)$ for arbitrary $x,y,w,z\in\mathbb H$ act on general $\varphi\in S_2(\mathbb H)$, it goes like
$$
[(x\otimes y)\tilde\otimes(z\otimes w)](\varphi):=\langle \varphi,z\otimes w\rangle_\text{HS} (x\otimes y)
$$
as defined by OP [in another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2677590/tensor-products-of-hilbert-spaces-and-hilbert-schmidt-operators). One readily verifies $\langle \varphi,z\otimes w\rangle_\text{HS} =\langle \varphi(w),z\rangle_{\mathbb H}$. The above map admits the trace
$$
\operatorname{tr}[(x\otimes y)\tilde\otimes(z\otimes w)]=\sum_{k,l\geq 1}\langle [(x\otimes y)\tilde\otimes(z\otimes w)](e_k\otimes e_l),e_k\otimes e_l\rangle_\text{HS}=\sum_{k,l\geq 1} \langle (e_k\otimes e_l)(w),z\rangle_{\mathbb H}\langle x,(e_k\otimes e_l)(y)\rangle_{\mathbb H}=\sum_{k,l\geq 1} \langle w,e_l\rangle_{\mathbb H}\langle e_k,z\rangle_{\mathbb H}\langle x,e_k\rangle_{\mathbb H}\langle e_l,y\rangle_{\mathbb H}=\langle w,y\rangle_{\mathbb H}\langle x,z\rangle_{\mathbb H}
$$
by basis expansion. On the other hand, $\operatorname{tr}(a\otimes b)=\langle a,b\rangle_{\mathbb H}$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb H$ (can also be easily seen by basis expansion). Piecing things together, one gets the somewhat peculiar identity
$$
\boxed{\operatorname{tr}[(x\otimes y)\tilde\otimes(z\otimes w)]=\operatorname{tr}(x\otimes z)\operatorname{tr}(w\otimes y)}
$$
so the trace identity in your answer is not correct. This is solely due to the above definition of the tensor product $\tilde\otimes$ to go from $S_2(\mathbb H)$ to operators on $S_2(\mathbb H)$ which does not coincide with the usual tensor product (as in that case one *would* in fact have $\operatorname{tr}(A\tilde\otimes B)=\operatorname{tr}(A)\operatorname{tr}(B)$ given $A,B$ are trace-class). To see how $(x\otimes y)\tilde\otimes (x\otimes y)$ should behave on $\mathbb H\otimes\mathbb H$ to mimic the usual tensor product of linear Hilbert space operators, check my old answer below.

---

**OLD ANSWER**:

To identify the Hilbert-Schmidt-Operators with $\mathbb H\otimes\mathbb H$ (as Peter Melech pointed out in his comment) and to not raise confusion regarding the actual Hilbert space tensor product $\otimes_{\mathbb H}=:\otimes$, I will "rename" your map $x\otimes y$ to $\langle \cdot,y\rangle x:\mathbb H\to\mathbb H$ (but the action is the same!). Consider the map
$$
A=(\langle \cdot,y\rangle x)\otimes(\langle \cdot,y\rangle x):\mathbb H\otimes \mathbb H\to\mathbb H\otimes \mathbb H
$$
defined via
$$
a\otimes b\mapsto (\langle a,y\rangle x)\otimes(\langle b,y\rangle x)=\langle a,y\rangle\langle b,y\rangle\, x\otimes x=\langle a\otimes b,y\otimes y\rangle\, x\otimes x
$$
and its linear extension onto all of $\mathbb H\otimes\mathbb H$, i.e., $$\boxed{A(z)=\langle z,y\otimes y\rangle x\otimes x}$$ for all $z\in\mathbb H\otimes\mathbb H$. [*Edit*: Thus in your notation and given your definition, the identity $$(x\otimes y)\tilde\otimes(x\otimes y)=(x\,\tilde\otimes \,x)\otimes(y\,\tilde\otimes \,y)$$ has to hold to mimic the usual tensor product of linear operators.] Now on the one hand,
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A)=\operatorname{tr}(\langle \cdot,y\otimes y\rangle\, x\otimes x)=\langle x\otimes x,y\otimes y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle^2\,.
$$
On the other hand, let $\lbrace e_k\rbrace_{k\geq 1}$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb H$, then $\lbrace e_k\otimes e_l\rbrace_{k,l\geq 1}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb H\otimes\mathbb H$. By definition of the trace
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A)=\sum_{k,l\geq 1}\langle A(e_k\otimes e_l),e_k\otimes e_l\rangle=
\sum_{k,l\geq 1}\langle e_k\otimes e_l,y\otimes y\rangle\langle x\otimes x,e_k\otimes e_l\rangle\\
=\Big\langle x\otimes x, \sum_{k,l\geq 1}\langle y\otimes y,e_k\otimes e_l\rangle e_k\otimes e_l\Big\rangle=\langle x\otimes x,y\otimes y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle^2
$$
where in the last step we just used the [basis expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis#Basic_formula) in $\mathbb H\otimes\mathbb H$.

Comment: Did'nt You change from $A=x\otimes y \tilde{\otimes}x\otimes y$ to $x\otimes x\tilde{\otimes}y\otimes y$?

Comment: Curiously for that map You could as well compute $Tr(x\otimes x\tilde{\otimes}y\otimes y)=Tr(x\otimes x)Tr(y\otimes y)=<x,x><y,y>=||x||^2||y||^2$!

Comment: Yes I guess in OP's notation the key result I used is $A=(x\otimes y)\tilde\otimes(x\otimes y)=(x\tilde\otimes x)\otimes(y\tilde\otimes y)$ ($\neq (x\otimes x)\tilde\otimes(y\otimes y)$ (!)). But this is why I personally am not too fond of this notation - it at least for me is quite easy to confuse $x\otimes y$ (the $\langle\cdot,y\rangle x$ pairing) and actual tensor products $x\tilde\otimes y$ in $\mathbb H\tilde\otimes\mathbb H$...

Comment: However the OP's map acts like $A(e_k\otimes e_l)=<e_k\otimes e_l,x\otimes y>x\otimes y$ whereas Your map acts like $A(e_k\otimes e_l)=<e_k\otimes e_l,y\otimes y>x\otimes x$ and the point is that for both(!) maps one gets two different results for the trace using the two different methods. I don't think it is a matter of misleading notation, there must be some more subtle mistake.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! After checking OP's definition of his map, I believe to have found the underlying mistake. Edited my answer.

Comment: Your peculiar identity looks quite strange (but is true I think) and it is really counterintuitive that the "mutiplicity" of the trace with the "tensor product" does not hold, as well it is unclear what a usual tensor product could be. However I agree that the mistake lies exactly here:+1